# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in a table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table of results and get plenty of `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` and `Overfull \hbox` error messages... Should I not put the `\newline`?

**Code:**

[image: code]

**Errors:**

[image: console errors]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your `\newline`s... don't use them. Do you want a blank line between paragraphs?

Comment: delete the \newlines and just leave a blank line in the source, also please post code as text not as an image, so people can test it and debug. the final error is unrelated to teh code you show, you have two mane `&` on a line